# How to efficiently set values of matrix with list entries in R?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am converting a list of numbers to a matrix.  The list of numbers is encoded text.  Each word has a number associated with it, like 'the': 1, 'it': 2, etc.  I want to get a matrix of values where the presence of an encoded word is represented by a '1'.  So if one of our encoded texts looked like:

```
c(1, 4, 2)
```

Then the corresponding matrix (with a max word index of 10) would look like:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

So here is how I have it currently:

```
encoded.text <- list(c(1, 3, 2), c(1, 7, 8))

result <- matrix(0, nrow = length(encoded.text), ncol = 10)

for (i in 1:length(encoded.text)) {
  result[i, encoded.text[[i]]] <- 1
}
```

I'm wondering, is there a better/more efficient way than the for loop to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `row/column` indexing.  We `unlist` the 'encoded.text' for the column index, while `rep`licate the sequence of the `list` with the `lengths` of the `list` as `row` index.  `cbind` it to make a row/column index matrix, extract the values of 'result' based on the index and assign it to 1

```
m1 <- cbind(rep(seq_along(encoded.text), lengths(encoded.text)), 
            unlist(encoded.text))
result[m1] <- 1
result
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#[2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0     0
```

NOTE: The `apply/Map` etc are just loops as `for` loop.  It wouldn't give any peformance increment except just to add as an answer

#### Benchmarks

```
n <- 1e6
test <- rep(encoded.text, n)
testresult <- matrix(0, nrow = length(test), ncol = 10)
testresult2 <- copy(testresult)
testresult3 <- copy(testresult)

system.time({
m2 <- cbind(rep(seq_along(test), lengths(test)), 
            unlist(test))
testresult[m2] <- 1
})
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.290   0.098   0.388 

system.time({
testresult2[do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, seq_len(length(test)), test))] <- 1

})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  8.383   0.462   8.787 

system.time({
 
 for (i in 1:length(test)) {
   testresult3[i, test[[i]]] <- 1
 }
 })
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.648   0.131   0.778
```

---

If we increase 'n' and rerun again (after constructing the data)

```
n <- 1e7

system.time({
 m2 <- cbind(rep(seq_along(test), lengths(test)), 
             unlist(test))
 testresult[m2] <- 1
 })
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.699   1.225   3.990  # almost 2 times efficient now

system.time({
 testresult2[do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, seq_len(length(test)), test))] <- 1
 
 })
#   user  system elapsed 
# 88.584   5.047  94.384 
 
 system.time({
 
  for (i in 1:length(test)) {
    testresult3[i, test[[i]]] <- 1
  }
  })
#   user  system elapsed 
#  5.734   0.742   6.461
```

-microbenchmark on `n <- 1e7` constructed data

```
ak <- function() {
    m2 <- cbind(rep(seq_along(test), lengths(test)), 
                 unlist(test))
     testresult[m2] <- 1
    
}

wfw <- function() {
for (i in 1:length(test)) {
    testresult3[i, test[[i]]] <- 1
  }

}
library(microbemchmark)
microbenchmark(ak(), wfw(), unit = 'relative', times = 20L)
#Unit: relative
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  ak() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20  a 
# wfw() 1.946415 1.945528 1.927263 1.926645 1.910907 1.940207    20   b
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a matrix of row and column values where we want to put 1 using `mapply`

```
result[do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, seq_len(length(encoded.text)), encoded.text))] <- 1

result
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#[2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0     0
```

Comment: As @akrun mentioned, this way is no faster than the way I have in the question.